# How to limit access to objects in the django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to limit access to objects in the django admin based on the currently logged in user. Example objects below.

```
class ObjectOne(models.Model):
    other-objecs = models.ManyToManyField(OtherObject)

class OtherObject(models.Model):
    somefield = models.TextField()
```

I have defined ModelAdmin objects for all objects registered with the adminsite. I override get_queryset and return a subset consisting of objects that belong to a particular user

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ConfigurableMenuItemAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
             return qs
        return qs.filter(organization__user_id=request.user.id)
```

When I list an object directly this code works how I expect and only the objects belonging to the logged in user are shown. However when adding/changing ObjectOne the manytomany field shows all objects in the system regardless of who is logged in. Is there some way to do what I'm trying to do. I want each user to only ever see objects they own.

Comment: Have you considered using Django Guardian? http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2/

Comment: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/

Comment: Found a solution - thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For anyone that has a similar objective and comes across this question. In your ModelAdmin class you override formfield_for_manytomany and filter the queryset. [Documentation Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey)